# STM32G0 core lockup during reset?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller

Using a STM32G0F06

I have a bootloader/application that I am debugging. I am facing a strange problem. Often, I command the app to drop to bootloader (via a software reset). When I execute the software reset code, occasionally the core locks up.

Here is a video showing the core registers and the disassembly as I step debug through the reset code:

https://youtu.be/8SxjNWpSIss

A couple of questions:

- Is this a MCU core lockup? If not, what is it? Does the PC go to 0x1FFF19A6 during a core lockup, or is that just random?
- How come the IWDG I have configured does not reset the MCU after it has locked up?
- Does it get locked up to? Is there some way I can programmatically recover from a core lockup: MCU pulls its' own external reset pin low?

Comment: Why do you change the priority group?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  What instruction address are you referring to?

Comment: You set it to zero. In your function when you reset the micro

Comment: I still don't follow what is the memory address of the instruction that you're referring to

Comment: So you did not write the code, I assume.

Comment: What code?  Which address?  what program counter value?

Comment: The code you show in your YT video.

Answer (score -1):

If the PC has the value 0x1F... I suspect that it is not locked up but running the internal boot ROM.  The boot ROM will either kick the watchdog itself or maybe turn it off, so that is why you can't rely on the watchdog to get out of it.  ST probably don't want you to debug the ROM, so maybe that is responsible for your further problems.

See [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for how to make sure you don't go into the boot ROM after you reset.